# ProGuard: keep private Inner Class

Tags: android, proguard

How to keep private Inner Class in ProGuard.
I am already using($ for inner class) below code in my proguard.cfg but its not working.

```
-keep public class com.xxx.droid.activity.LoginActivity$JsInterface
```

Comment: I know this is old - may not get seen. Having a similar problem but the answer gives me a proguard error 'unknown class'

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
-keep public class com.xxx.droid.activity.LoginActivity$* {
        *;
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

If the inner class is private, you shouldn't use the `public` keyword in the template, because it won't match. The compiler will actually compile the class as a package visible class (private classes don't exist at a bytecode level). Therefore:

```
-keep class com.xxx.droid.activity.LoginActivity$JsInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```